# how to execute a javascript function in jsfiddle by pickink external variable

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

I am new to javascript and am trying to execute a function using jsfiddle and see what the output of the function would be.

below is my javascript code:

```
    function calculate(num) {
var body = JSON.parse(num);
   if(body.lastName=='M'){
     return 'true';
   }else{
     return 'false';
   }   
};
var testData= {"firstname":"Joe","lastName":"M"};
document.body.innerHTML=calculate(testData);
```

I would like to display the result of calculate(testData) in the result section of fiddle. How can i write the html to do this?

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML=calculate(testData);`

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/49LzznkL/ It works, just as @RayonDabre mentioned before.

Comment: The easiest way to execute a function is to open your browser's developer tools and run the function in the console.

Comment: @RayonDabre I am trying to pass a JSON data to the function and trying to access its attrbutes within the function

Comment: `lastName` is a property not method so don't use `()` to access it;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ;)

```js
function printIt(testData) {
  /* lastName is a property not method so don't use `()`; */
  return testData.lastName;
};

var testData = {"firstname": "Joe",
                "lastName": "M"};

document.write(printIt(testData));
```

**UPDATE 1**

```js
function printIt(testData) {
  /* lastName is a property not method so don't use `()`; */
  return testData.lastName;
};

var testData = {"firstname": "Joe",
                "lastName": "M"};

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = printIt(testData);
```

```html
<div id="output">
</div>
```

Comment: is there any other way i can do it? because fiddle shows a warning document.write is disallowed in JSFiddle environment and might break your fiddle. when i execute this